# Are there any libraries for predicate argument context constraints?

Tags: wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation

I'm trying to do word sense disambiguation with WordNet's verb frames, but they lack constraints on the predicate arguments, so there is no way to disambiguate using just the verb frames.

I could add the constraints manually, but I wanted to see if someone had done so already. Are there publicly available collections of verb frames marked with predicate argument context constraints? I'm using Java and GATE to call WordNet, if the programming language and environment matter.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it is what you're looking for but, have you taken a look at VerbNet? http://verbs.colorado.edu/~mpalmer/projects/verbnet.html

Comment: @aquiros Haven't quite gotten to VerbNet yet, but I plan to look into it. I'm also looking at FrameNet and PropBank. Of these three, which would you suggest for a Java user? Thanks.